# Solr Spatial Search: "can not use FieldCache on multivalued field"

Tags: solr, geospatial

I'm getting this message from Solr.

The relevant line on my schema.xml puts the location field as a non multiValued Field as shown below.

```
<field name="latlong_current" type="location" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Has anyone else run into this with the spatial search feature?

Comment: It's been a while, does Solr 4.8.x supports this feature??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used location fieldtypes, but I would look to make sure the analysis on that type isn't breaking it into multiple tokens. Apparently there's a LatLonType for storing geocodes, is "location" set to that?

Otherwise, the Solr people are really responsive on their mailing list and on IRC, if you don't get the answer you want here, try there!

Answer (score 0):

If you have these fields in your schema.xml as you should, make sure they are set to multiValued=false

```
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```